# TLS Handshake message parsing

Tags: c++, networking, ssl, proxy, openssl

I am currently trying to implement a tls handshake into a http proxy that I am writing. I know that I could use OpenSSL to do the work for me but I am interested in writing it myself.

I am currently working through the TLS RFC and am confused about how to parse the ClientHello message, particularly the fact that it may or may not have a session ID and that there seems to be a no count on the number of ciphersuites or compression methods.

Does anyone know the best way of doing this?

Comment: "How do I implement TLS" is quite probably far too broad.

Comment: My issue is not with implementing the whole thing, the problem is that i dont know how to handle the cases where things are optional and it doesn't seem to have an element in the message telling me how many items there will be.

Comment: I don't know why you want to do this at all. It isn't necessary to process the content in any way to write an HTTP proxy, other than the CONNECT command. If your proxy is an SSL endpoint you should certainly be using OpenSSL, and if you aren't an SSL endpoint again you have no need to parse SSL either, just send it straight through.

Comment: I wanted to implement an SSL proxy and didn't want to use OpenSSL as I wanted to experiment with using a GPU to do some of the cryptographic work.

I searched for this issue and found nothing because every responce about SSL was people telling other people to use OpenSSL. Sometimes it is good to reimplement something and not just use someone elses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The session_id is preceded by the length.  Same with the cipher suites and compression algorithms.

What's you're missing is section 4.3 of the RFC:

> Variable length vectors are defined by specifying a subrange of legal
>      lengths, inclusively, using the notation .  When
>      encoded, **the actual length precedes the vector's contents in the byte
>      stream**. The length will be in the form of a number consuming as many
>      bytes as required to hold the vector's specified maximum (ceiling)
>      length. A variable length vector with an actual length field of zero
>      is referred to as an empty vector.

Comment: Ye, unfortunatly I missed that the first time around. I read through it a few more times and finally caught that line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read byte by byte and parse it with your own code. Start with byte[0]. For some parts like sessionID which may not be there you have two bytes called sessionIDLength that it tells you how many bytes you expect to have as sessionID from the next bytes followed.

Or for example for serverName that could be different you have an identifier that tells you how many bytes are in the following for serverName (SNI)

For more information check this page to understand exactly the bytes that you need to parse them and the positions [HERE](https://tls12.xargs.org/)

I tried to do it like following (You need to implement it by yourself and it is just an example to give you an overview. Here I parsed it till serverName)

```cpp
std::string data="string of your client hello request, I assume that you converted the hexadecimal array to string, like following string";

// like 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

struct RecordHeader{
    std::string type,
                            version;
    unsigned short int  contentLength;              
};

struct HandshakeHeader{
    std::string messageType;
    unsigned short int  messageLength;
};

struct ClientHello{
    std::string clientVersion,
                            clientRandomValue,
                            sessionID,
                            serverName;
    unsigned short int  sessionIDLength,
                                            cipherSuitesLength,
                                            compressionMethodLength,
                                            extentionsLength,
                                            serverNameLength;
};


void parse(){
    parseRecordHeader();
    parseHandshakeHeader();
    parseClientHello();
}

void parseRecordHeader(){
    std::string tmpStr;
    unsigned short pos=0;
    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 2);
    if (tmpStr == "16"){
        recordHeader.type="TLS Handshake";
        pos += 2; // 2
    
        tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 2);
        recordHeader.version = std::to_string(hexToInt(tmpStr));
        pos += 2; // 4
        tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 2);
        recordHeader.version = recordHeader.version+"."+std::to_string(hexToInt(tmpStr));
        pos += 2; // 6
    
        tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 4);
        recordHeader.contentLength = hexToInt(tmpStr);
        pos += 4; // 10
    }
}

void parseHandshakeHeader(){
    std::string tmpStr;
    unsigned short pos=10;
    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 2);
    if (tmpStr == "01"){
        handshakeHeader.messageType="ClientHello";
    }
    pos += 2; // 12
    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 6);
    handshakeHeader.messageLength = hexToInt(tmpStr);
    pos += 6; // 18
}

void parseClientHello(){
    std::string tmpStr;
    unsigned short pos=18;
    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 2);
    clientHello.clientVersion = std::to_string(hexToInt(tmpStr));
    pos += 2; // 20
    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 2);
    clientHello.clientVersion = clientHello.clientVersion+"."+std::to_string(hexToInt(tmpStr));
    pos += 2; // 22
    
    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 64);
    clientHello.clientRandomValue = tmpStr;

    pos += 64; // 82
    
    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 2);
    clientHello.sessionIDLength = hexToInt(tmpStr);
    pos += 2; // 84
    
    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, clientHello.sessionIDLength);
    clientHello.sessionID = tmpStr;
    pos = pos + (clientHello.sessionIDLength * 2); // ??
    
    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 4);
    clientHello.cipherSuitesLength = hexToInt(tmpStr);
    pos += 4; // ??
    pos = pos + (clientHello.cipherSuitesLength * 2); // ??

    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 2);
    clientHello.compressionMethodLength = hexToInt(tmpStr);
    pos += 2; // ??
    pos = pos + (clientHello.compressionMethodLength * 2); // ??
        
    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 4);
    clientHello.extentionsLength = hexToInt(tmpStr);
    pos += 4; // ??
        
    tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 4);
    if ( hexToInt(tmpStr) == 0 ){
        pos += 14;
        tmpStr = data.substr(pos, 4);
        clientHello.serverNameLength = hexToInt(tmpStr);
        pos += 4;
        tmpStr = data.substr(pos, clientHello.serverNameLength * 2);
        clientHello.serverName = hexToASCII(tmpStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [THIS INCREDIBLE BOOK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470920416). I had to implement the TLS 1.2 for an embedded system without using any GPL software and this was enormously helpful.